# "Unfortunately, App name has stopped" Simple app

Tags: android

I'm starting to learn Android app development. In Android Studio gradle didn't show any error. But showed "Unfortunately, App name has stopped" on my phone. I'm trying to make simple EditTex to textview via button app. I think that is easy, but clearly ins't. At least with this fatal error. I hope you can help me in this situation. And maybe this is dum question.

Here's the logcat

```
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.winwin.kapurs.tester1, PID: 26610
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.winwin.kapurs.tester1/com.winwin.kapurs.tester1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime: at com.winwin.kapurs.tester1.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:11)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Here's my main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final EditText mess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (txt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            String editTextValue = mess.getText().toString();
            txt.setText(editTextValue);
        } else {
            txt.setText("");
            mess.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: (the variables don't have to be `final`)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mess;
TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (txt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        String editTextValue = mess.getText().toString();
        txt.setText(editTextValue);
    } else {
        txt.setText("");
        mess.setText("");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move these initializations (keep the variable declaration)

```
final EditText mess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

to `onCreate()` so that it won't NPE due to activity window not being initialized yet, and after `setContentView()` so that the returned value can be non-null.

Comment: Well, I moved these initializations to 'onCreate()', but then got 4 error's for unknow variable in 'onClick(View v)'

Comment: Of course, keep the variable declaration at class level but initialization in `onCreate()`